# Does pyrogram support Finite State Machine or FSM for short

Tags: python, telegram, fsm, pyrogram

**Good time of a day to you all!**

**Short Question:** Does pyrogram support FSM how it's implemented in AIOGram?

**Long Question:** I'm just searching for a telegram API wrapper other than AIOgram and PyTelegramBotApi and found this. I read documentation intro for Pyrogram and liked those features and pros. But I was unable to locate any information regarding the existence of an FSM-like feature in Pyrograms. So, does Pyrogram have FSM in it?

Tried to search for "FSM in Pyrogram" or longer "Finite State Machine in Pyrogram". Searched for FSM/Finite State Machine in official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no in-built FSM in pyrogram as of now. You have to manually code it yourself with support from third party libraries such as [transitions](https://github.com/pytransitions/transitions)